# How do I control dataGridViewColumn order for custom business objects?

Tags: .net, datagridview, business-objects

Creating a custom business object to slide into a dataGridView works wonders... except I can't think of a programmatic way to set the column order.

Do I have to add them one by one by hand manually again just to get a nicer sort or is there some cryptic hidden attribute I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each dataGridViewColumn as a DisplayIndex Property which can be applied at any time and even works with AutoGenerateColumns set to true.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["colName"].DisplayIndex = 0;
dataGridView1.Columns["colAnotherColumn"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

Comment: right, but this requires that everytime I remove a column from the datasource, if I miss removing it from the sort, I now have an exception when it can't find "colName". I was hoping for a more dynamic solution like an attribute tag I could put on the business object properties.

Comment: accepting this answer as the easiest way, although I really wish there was a more strongly typed option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you currently have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`.  The only way I know to control the order of the columns is to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and, like you said, manually add the columns.

**EDIT:**

---

I just looked into a vague memory of another way of doing this and think that you may want to look into the `GridView` control's `ColumnsGenerator` property which takes a `IAutoFieldGenerator` object.  This interface has one method called `GenerateFields' which takes a`Control`(the`Grid`) and returns an` ICollection ` (of Fields).